# VS 2010 Beta2 Integration Project Exp hive output?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am in the process of upgrading an existing VS Integration Project to 2010 Beta2. The project uses Spring. The Initialize() code in the VSPkg.cs includes a call that tries to access an XML file that contains some context settings. The xml file properties are set to the Build Action = Content and Copy to Output Directory = Copy always. The file indeed appears in the  output directory (bin\Debug). BUT, by some default the build output also ends up in the Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0Exp\Extensions\\\. The contents of this directory is apparently used to initialize the Experimental Hive when I try to debug.  The problem is that only the dll files, pkgdef file and vsixmanifest get copied there. How can I make my XML file to be copied there as well? Since it is not there I get an IO exception "Can't find file..." during the Initialize().

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a post-build action?